# can not click on none visible element

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test my angularjs app with protractorjs. I have set up selenium and got the server and runner working. My issue is that when I run my test I get the ElementNotVisibleError. I know that the element I am trying to select is hidden until certain fields have been filled in and this is how I would like this to be kept.

My question is, are there any workarounds to the issue via a call to wait or sleep. I have tried many variations of wait and sleep but with no luck.

My test code is

```
it('navigates the user to the login page', function(){
    ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    ptor.get('http://localhost:2222/#/page');

    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type1')).sendKeys('one');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type2')).sendKeys('two');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type3')).sendKeys('three');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type4')).sendKeys('four');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type5')).sendKeys('five');
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type6')).sendKeys('six');
    ptor.sleep(5000);
    ptor.findElement(protractor.By.id('clickableBtn')).click();//not visible until above fields populated

}, 1000000);
```

Message from protractor is

```
Message:
    ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible
```

Comment: So you are inputting those fields as I can see, and the element should now be visible but isn't?

Comment: the issue seems to be that the tests are running faster than the browser. I have set the `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20);` but this does not seem to help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element is not visible until you have input in all of the fields, it is because of Javascript.  You may have to kick off that Javascript by typing `Tab` or `Enter` after typing that last field:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.input('input.type6')).sendKeys(Keys.Tab);
```

Comment: You are right, I did need to kick off the button. I could not send Keys.Tab as Keys does not exist so I decided to change the value os input.type5 which kicked off the button. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Using javascript I was able to click

```
var linkToClick = ptor.driver.findElement(protractor.By.id('clickableBtn'));

ptor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", linkToClick );
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, WebDriver allows you to execute javascript on elements directly so simply do a javascript .click.  You would need to convert to your own language but here is how I did it using C#

```
        IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
        js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", element);
        Browser.WaitForPageLoad(driver);
```

I actually created an extender method so that I simply type element.InvisibleClick(driver) and it clicks on it for me.  More on that can be found [documented HERE](http://brantleytec.blogspot.com/2013/02/webdriver-click-on-hidden-links.html).

Answer (score -1):

You can always give it `opacity:0`

```
-moz-opacity: 0.00; opacity:.00; filter: alpha(opacity=00);
```

This should work for all browsers.

Comment: wouldn't this make it, invisible?